# How to get in-memory size of the ParquetWriter object before closing it and writing it to disk?

Tags: java, hadoop, avro, parquet

I am reading Avro messages from a stream and writing them out into a Parquet file using parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter. I am trying to have the size of the output files above a threshold limit. the problem is that ParquetWriter keeps everything in memory and only writes it out to disk at the end when writer is closed. Based on Parquet documentation, the data is written into memory object in the final format, meaning that the size of the object in memory is the same as the final size on disk. My question is how to get the size of the written data in memory in order to decide on closing the writer?

I tried using the byte size of the avro messages that I write to ParquetWriter as an estimate for the Parquet writer file size but that is very different than the parquet writer size because of the different way parquet store data (columnar format). Here's the pseudo code for what I did:

```
    ParquetWriter parquetWriter = new ParquetWriter(..., BLOCK_SIZE, PAGE_SIZE);    
    long bytesWrittenSofar = 0;

    public long getLength(){
        return bytesWrittenSofar;
    }
    public void write(org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord record){
        parquetWriter.write(record);
        bytesWrittenSofar += avroToBytes(record).length;
    }

    public static byte[] avroToBytes(GenericRecord record){
        GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer =
            new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(record.getSchema());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BinaryEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null);
        writer.write(record, encoder);
        encoder.flush();
        out.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
```

It turned out that value I get from getLength() is very different than actual file size of the parquet file. I know that the schema will be added at the end of the file but that is very small. Just to give you an idea, When getLength() reports 130MB, the actual file size is only 80MB.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to access the memory used by ParquetWriter. Instead, I ended up profiling uploaded file sizes and the number of records written in them. Using previous data and by counting the number of records written to the current file, I estimated the file size of the current in progress file. This turned out to be much closer to real file size than any other try. However, it highly depends on the application and the variation in records that you write.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely one of the later additions to the API which was not available at the time of writing of the question.

The method [`ParquetWriter#getDataSize()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.parquet/parquet-hadoop/1.10.1/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetWriter.html#getDataSize--) should give you what you need.